# What are the variables of derivative of multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When we have multivariable function F(t)=f(x(t),y(t)), and we find derivative of F with respect to t.... in our derivative the first member is df/dx*dx/dt + .....) Why df/dx depends on x and y. Thank you.
(My question was written incorrectly (before))

Comment: Note that in the equation "$f(t) = f(x(t),y(t))$" the same letter $f$ is being used as a name for two different functions. It would be better to say something like $F(t) = f(x(t),y(t))$.

Comment: thanx,__________

Comment: Sure. The way it was written previously is a common "abuse of notation", so you will see it written that way in many places. But I think that your revised version is more clear.

Comment: "abuse of notation" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $t$ is irrelevant here.

The partial derivative $f'_x(x,y)$ measures the slope of the graph $z=f(x,y)$ in the $x$ direction at the point $(x,y)$, and of course that slope can be different **at different points**. So it depends on $x$ and $y$, in general.

Comment: I know it depends on x and y in general, but in my mind :) when we derive with resp. to x we set y for example y=7, so at the end we have slops in points like (x,7). Its weird to me that once y is constant and then its variable ( i have i problem when searching for second part. derivative).

Comment: @mmm: When you compute the partial at one particular point $(x,y)=(a,b)$, you keep $y=b$ constant and let $x$ vary around $a$. Then you do the same thing at another point $(x,y)=(c,d)$: keep $y=d$ constant and let $x$ vary around $c$. Of course the result should depend on which point you chose to look at to begin with, shouldn't it? That's all there is to it.

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark yes, thank you)

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question in two ways

**Interpretation 1:**

Let's take an example :

$f(x(t),y(t))=x^2+y$

and $x=t, y=2t$

Our partial derivative with respect to x is $f_x=2x$.

However,

$x=t, y=2t =>t=y/2=x$

So, our partial derivatice with respect to x could be written as $f_x=y$, since x and y are related by a shared parameter t.

**Interpretation 2:**

Let's take another example

$f(x(t),y(t))=x^2+xy^2$

So our partial derivative with respect to x is $f_x=2x+y^2$, since the derivative of $ax$ with respect to x is just $a$.

It so happens that our $a$ in this case is $y$. Remember that when dealing with partial derivatives and gradients, you are measuring the slope, in 3D cases and higher dimensions, slope can depend on more than one variable. Think about it like the steepness of climbing a mountain: how steep the climb up is depends on both x (the how you approach the climb) and y (assuming the mountain gets steeper as you proceed to the top).

Comment: thank you for your time, but it doesnt seem to answer my question, which is little bit weird by itself